# return in if statement throws conversion error

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I will apologize in advance for the long post. Just trying to give you all the information I have.

I have an `if` statement in a method that looks like this:

```cs
var comparison = await SystemService.SearchCount();
var fileExporter = Configure();
var fileName = "SearchResults"

if (defaultValue <= comparison)
{
   var result = SearchResult.Rows.Where(s => VSR.Any(s2 => s2.ID == s.Values.FirstOrDefault()));
   var records = SearchResult.Rows.ToList();
   await Task.Yield();
   return fileExport.ToCsv(records, fileName);
}
```

The error that I am getting is the following error:

> cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.List<SearchRows>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IList<SearchResults>`'

I tried to change the return to explicitly cast to `IList` like this:

```cs
return fileExport.ToCsv((IList<SearchResults>)records, fileName);
```

This will let it build in Visual Studio but it throws an InvalidCastException when I run it and look at the developer tools:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[SearchRow] to type System.Collections.Generic.IList[SearchResult].

What am I missing here? I don't see an issue at all with the code.

The SearchResults model is a listing of the records to be returned (Id, name etc)

The SearchRows model serves as a wrapper for the columns and rows (I didn't name these they came in with the legacy code)

Comment: Your lists are holding different types: SearchRow vs SearchResult.

Comment: That is suspiciously similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72221327) from a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`records` is of type `List<SearchRow>`, which is not compatible with the type `List<SearchResult>`, you either have to convert the `SearchRows` to `SearchResults` (e.g. via a `Select`) or alter the type accepted by `ToCSV`

Comment: Thank you @Nick Bailey I am not super familiar with linq statements would you have an example of this.  I am assuming that is what you meant by (e.g. via a Select)

Comment: Sure, on mobile now, I'll try to add one later. Would be easier if you could include the type definitions for searchresult and searchrow

Comment: they are both vars

Comment: No i meant what the classes look like.

Comment: Sorry it has been a long day for me.  I will add them to the question

Comment: Hah no worries!